# Iterate in reverse given the bound iterators of a range C++

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a vector `std::vector<int> nums;` and I have two iterators `lower_boud` and `upper_bound`. I want to traverse `nums` from `upper_bound` to `lower_boud` while applying a function to numbers without using loops or allocating any memory. I have found `std::transform` but I'm not sure how to traverse in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

One can use `std::reverse_iterator` to change direction of any bidirectional iterator. Just be careful that `std::transform(b,e,...)` requires `b<=e` so the positions of reversed iterators must be exchanged.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    auto lb = std::lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 2);
    auto ub = std::upper_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 8);

    std::vector<int> out1;
    std::cout << "FORWARD\n";
    std::transform(lb, ub, std::back_inserter(out1), [](const auto& e) {
        std::cout << "Transforming forward:" << e << '\n';
        return e;
    });
    std::cout << "REVERSED\n";
    std::vector<int> out2;
    std::transform(std::reverse_iterator(ub), std::reverse_iterator(lb),
                   std::back_inserter(out2), [](const auto& e) {
                       std::cout << "Transforming backward:" << e << '\n';
                       return e;
                   });
}
```

Output:

```
FORWARD
Transforming forward:2
Transforming forward:4
Transforming forward:5
Transforming forward:6
Transforming forward:7
Transforming forward:8
REVERSED
Transforming backward:8
Transforming backward:7
Transforming backward:6
Transforming backward:5
Transforming backward:4
Transforming backward:2
```

Comment: As is, violates the requirement of *'not allocating any memory'* – you'd some kind of ignoring insertion iterator instead of the `std::back_inserter` for the second vector.

Comment: @Aconcagua Fair enough, I mean it is just an example, OP did not specify where to store the transformed result.

Comment: Not storing at all – wanting just to iterate over `std::for_each` is the way to go. OP apparently just *stumbled over* `std::transform` (-> *'I have found'*), but that's not the right one here ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua That is possible, we won't know until OP says more.

Comment: Hm... Not wanting to store the result anywhere is expressed clearly and explicitly enough, I'd say (*'I want to [...] without [...] allocating any memory'*). Absolutely wanting to use `std::transform`? I'd have considered the uncertainty about alike – but if indeed *not*, then we might revert the vector in place (don't think this can be done with `std::transform` at all, however, though there's `std::reverse` then) – or we need a standard iterator ignoring the data received or write custom one on our own if need be...

Answer (score 1):

`std::transform` is the wrong standard algorithm if you just want to iterate over the elements, as it requires another iterator to insert the transformed results to (of which the target then requires additional memory). Instead [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) is your friend then, in combination with [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator). Note that as you want to iterate from `ub` down to `lb` you need to use the reversed `ub` as starting index and the reversed `lb` as ending one (this part adopted from [Quimby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7691729/quimby)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74051131/1312382)):

```
std::for_each(std::reverse_iterator(ub), std::reverse_iterator(lb), f);
```

with `f` being the function to be applied.

An alternative approach is searching the right iterators directly from the `std::vector`:

```
auto lb = std::lower_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), maxValue, std::greater<int>());
auto ub = std::upper_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), minValue, std::greater<int>());

std::for_each(lb, ub, f);
```

Note that the definition of lower and upper bound applied here contradict the natural feeling of these bounds – in the sense of the inverted comparison – `std::greater`(!) – they still remain correct (a greater value in this specific context counts as *less* from point of view of the two bound-finding algorithms), thus the inverted minimum/maximum values as well. For the same reason/in the same sense – and as using the reverse iterators of `std::vector` – we can iterate from 'lower' to 'upper' just normally.

Comment: Side note: If having to apply *lambdas* anyway, then classic loops (yes, you explicitly excluded…) still can yield simpler code, though admitted, in case of first variant (corresponding to the example using `std::reverse_iterator`) care has to be taken a bit on correctly iterating downwards (special case of `lb` marking the begin, as one cannot decrement it further then): `while(ub-- != lb) { use *ub }` or, if yet needing the original upper bound: `for(auto i = ub; i-- != lb) { use *i }` analogously to down-counting unsigned integrals: `for(unsigned i = 4; i-- != 0;) { i == 3,2,1,0 }`.